# Excessive delegation design

Tags: java, design-patterns, delegates

I see quite a lot of this kind of design patterns in our code. Does it look reasonable to you?

```
interface A {
    void doSmth();
}

interface B extends A {

}

class C implements A {
    A a;

    public C(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    @Override
    public void doSmth() {

    }
}

class D implements B {
    A a;

    public D() {
        a = new C(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void doSmth() {
        a.doSmth();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Usage of certain design patterns is usually driven by specific motiviations/requirements.

Comment: I think you should provide a better example...

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a "composition" or "strategy" pattern. Using IoC you pass the class which is actually responsible of doing something.

Without knowing the purpose of your SW and your requirements, it is not easy to give you an answer, but in any case, it is a good design to rely on such patterns.